# Div not displaying images & nav bar issues

Tags: html, css

I am a newb here. I have been attempting to fix this code for the past couple days to no avail. I am trying to create a page that is reactive. It was working well before I added media queries and made some other small changes. I currently can not get the images to appear on the schedule and classes pages (#lounge , #mat). I also cannot get the nav bar to no longer be stuck in two columns.

index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href =yoga.css>

<title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>
<div id="wrapper">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
    <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>

  <header class="home">
    <h1><a href="index.html">Path of Light Yoga Studio</a></h1>
  </header>



  <main>

  <h2>Find Your Inner Light</h2>
  <p><span class="studio">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span> welcomes all to experience a yoga practice in a tranquil,<br> peaceful
  enviroment.Our studio offers classes at every level, from beginner to <br> advanced. Whether you are new to yoga
  or have been practicing for years,<br> our dedicated instructors can modify a practice to help you improve your well-<br>being. 
  Let your inner light shine at the <span class="studio">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span>.</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Hatha, Vinyasa, Restorative Yoga classes</li>
    <li>Drop-ins welcome</li>
    <li>Mats, blocks, and blankets provided</li>
    <li>Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="clear">Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>612 Serenity Way<br>El Dorado, CA 96162
  <br><br>
  <a id="mobile" href="tell:888-555-555">888-555-5555</a>
  <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
  </div>

  </main>

  <br><br>
  <br><br>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2020 Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
  <a href="mailto:amanda@alcottherr.com"> amanda@alcottherr.com </a>
  </footer>

</div>


schedule.hmtl
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">>
<link rel="stylesheet" href =yoga.css>

<title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>

<head>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
<li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<header class="content">
    <h1><a href="index.html">Path of Light Yoga Studio</a></h1>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">

<main>
<div id="loungehero"></div>
<h2>Yoga Schedule</h2>
<p> Mats, blocks and blankets provided. Please arrive 10 minutes before your class begins.
Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class.
</p>

<div id="flow">
<section >
<h3>Monday - Friday</h3>

<ul>
<li>9:00am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
<li>10:30am Vinyasa Yoga</li>
<li>5:30pm Restorative Yoga</li>
<li>7:00pm Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
</ul>
</section>

<section >
<h3>Saturday &amp; Sunday </h3>

<ul>
<li>10:30am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
<li>Noon Vinyasa Yoga</li>
<li>1:30am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
<li>3:00pm Vinyasa Yoga</li>
<li>5:30pm Restorative Yoga</li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>

</main>

<br><br>
<footer>
<small><i>Copyright &copy; 2020 Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
<a href="mailto:amanda@alcottherr.com"> amanda@alcottherr.com </a>
</i>
</small>

</footer>
</div>


classes.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href =yoga.css>

<title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>

<div id="wrapper">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
     <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <header class="content">
    <h1><a href="index.html">Path of Light Yoga Studio</a></h1>
  </header>


  <main>

    <div id="mathero"></div>

  <h2>Yoga Classes</h2>

  <div id="flow">
    <section>
    <h3>Gentle Hatha Yoga</h3>
    <p> A 60 minute class of poses and slow movement that focuses on asana(proper alignment 
    and posture), pranayama (breath work), and guided meditation to foster your mind and body connection.
    This class is intended for beginners and anyone wishing a grounded foundation in the practice of yoga.</P>
    </section>

    <section >
    <h3>Vinyasa Yoga</h3>
    <p>A 60 minute class that focuses on breath synchronized movement - you will inhale and exhale as you 
    flow energetically through yoga poses. While intended for intermediate to advanced students,
    beginners are welcome to join in this class.</p>
    </section>

    <section >
    <h3>Restorative Yoga</h3>
    <p>A 90 minute class that features very slow movement and long poses.Restorative yoga is useful in 
    relieving stress and fostering a sense of well-being. This clamins, restorative experience is suitable 
    for students of any level of experience</p>
    </section>
  </div>


  </main>

  <br><br>

  <footer>

  <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2020 Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
  <a href="mailto:amanda@alcottherr.com"> amanda@alcottherr.com </a>
  </i>

  </small>

  </footer>

</div>



yoga.css

* { box-sizing: border-box;}

nav ul {display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    margin:0;
    font-size:1.2em;
    list-style:none;}

nav li {
    width:40%;
    padding:0 1em 0 1em;
    display:inline;}

nav{position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    width:100%;    
    padding-top:0.5em;
    padding-right:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:9999;}

nav a{display: block;
    text-decoration:none;}
    
nav a:link{color:#3F2860;}
nav a:visited{color:#497777;}
nav a:hover {color: #A26100;}

header {background-color: #40407A;
    background-image:url(sunrise.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    color:white;
    font-size:90%;
    margin-top:50px;
    min-height:200px;
    text-decoration:none;}

header a:link{color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;}
header a:visited{color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;}
header a:hover{color:#EDF5F5;text-decoration:none;}

h1 {text-decoration: none;}

.home {height:20vh;
    padding:2em 0 0 10%;}

.content {height:20vh;
    padding:2em 0 0 10%;}

#wrapper{background-color: #F5F5F5;
   padding:2em;}

body {background-color: #3F2860;
    color:#40407A;
    font-family: Arial, 
        'Segoe UI', 
        Tahoma, 
        Geneva,
        Verdana, 
        sans-serif;
    margin:0}

.studio {font-style: italic;}

#mathero{background-image:url(yogamat.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:300px ;
    display:none;}

#loungehero{background-image:url(yogalounge.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:300px ;
    display:none;}

section {padding:0 .5em 0 .5em;}    

footer {
    font-size:0.6em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align:center;}

#mobile{ display:inline;}

#desktop{display:none;}

@media (max-width:600px){
    nav ul {display:flex;
        flex-flow:row nowrap;
        justify-content:flex-end;}
    nav li { width:7em;}
    section{ padding:0 2em 0 2em;}
    #mathero{ display:block;
            padding-bottom:1em;}
    #loungeher0{ display:block;
        padding-bottom:1em;}
    #flow{display:flex;
        flex-flow:row;}
    #mobile{display:none;}
    #desktop{display:inline;}
    }

@media(min-width:1024px){
    header {font-size:120%;}
    .home {height: 50vh;
        padding:5em 0 0 8em;}
    .content {height:30vh;
        padding:1em 0 0 8em;}
    #wrapper {margin:auto;
        width:80%;}
}
```

Comment: About the images. The elements you are trying to display the background-images for, are empty, so they don't have any width or height. Add those properties to the elements and give them some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your navbar:
You have the width of each li set to 40%, this means the 40% of your window width.

```
nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(7em, 1fr));
}
nav li {
    padding:0 1em 0 1em;
}
```

As for your pictures, the containers `#loungehero`and `#mathero` (if you remove the `display:none;`) have 0 height.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the nav bar. With some trial and error I finally got my images to display correctly using the following code.      #mathero{background-image:url(yogamat.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:300px;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    padding:1em;
}

#loungehero{background-image:url(yogalounge.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:300px;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    padding:1em;}